# Critical Reynolds numbers for turbulence in 3D and 2D planar Couette flows

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems, fluid-dynamics, chaos, navier-stokes

In 3 spatial dimensions, the incompressible Navier-Stokes equations are:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial t} + \sum_{j=1}^3 u_j \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} &= - \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i} +  \nu \sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_j^2}\qquad\text{ for } i=1,2,3\\
\sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_j} & = 0 
\end{split}
$$
Let me consider only general planar [Couette boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couette_flow), force periodic boundary conditions (in two of the three dimensions), and normalize without loss of generality (so $1/\nu$ is the Reynolds number):
$$
\begin{split}
u_2(x_1,1,x_3,t)&=u_2(x_1,-1,x_3,t)=u_3(x_1,1,x_3,t)=u_3(x_1,-1,x_3,t)=0\\
u_1(x_1,1,x_3,t)&=-u_1(x_1,-1,x_3,t)=1\\
\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_2}(x_1,1,x_3,t)&=\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_2}(x_1,-1,x_3,t)=0\\
\\
u_i(x_1,x_2,x_3,t)&=u_i(x_1+L,x_2,x_3,t)=u_i(x_1,x_2,x_3)\qquad\text{ for }i=1,2,3\\
p(x_1,x_2,x_3,t)&=p(x_1+L,x_2,x_3,t)=p(x_1,x_2,x_3+W,t)
\end{split}
$$
A lot of numerical research goes into finding the largest $\nu$ which allows a forever-turbulent solution (i.e., allows a solution with no steady limit as $t\to\infty$).  This maximum value seems to be [about 1/350](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0701235).  If I force $W=L=5$, I too can simulate this turbulence for $\nu$=1/625.

In 2D, however, most experts seem to believe that any initial condition (no matter how "swirly" or how singular, as long as the derivatives written above exist) and any non-zero positive $\nu$ (and any $L$), will decay to the laminar Couette solution as $t\to\infty$:
$$
u_1=x_2~~~~~~~u_2=0~~~~~~~u_3=0\\
p=p_\infty~~\text{(some constant, independent of position and time)}
$$
In other words, the 2D critical Reynolds number is infinite.  What is the best argument for this?  I don't believe a proof has ever been given.

Comment: Do you have some reference(s) suggesting that "most experts seem to believe that any initial condition... will decay to the laminar Couette solution," that is, global asymptotic stability? I haven't seen that assertion before (which doesn't mean much...).

Comment: @sharpend Sorry, I don't have a reference and it's more of a gut feeling from watching many people speak about how vortex-stretching is only possible in 3D.  I am of course welcoming for someone to disagree (hopefully with a good 2D example where turbulence seems likely).

Comment: Sure, there is no vortex stretching in 2d, but that alone doesn't suggest to me that Couette should be globally asymptotically stable at all Re in 2d, as there can still be "2d turbulence," which looks quite different from 3d turbulence... I don't have a good book reference, but there is a course by Greg Eyink: https://www.ams.jhu.edu/~eyink/TurbulenceIII/
With that said, I don't know the answer to your question (and would like to know).

Answer (score 1):

Two-dimensional plane-periodic Couette flow is non-turbulent for long times at any Reynolds number. The mechanism by which laminar flow is recovered is analyzed in [Enhanced dissipation and inviscid damping in the inviscid limit of the Navier-Stokes equations near the 2D Couette flow](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.4754), see also [Stability of the Couette flow
at high Reynolds numbers in two dimensions and three dimensions](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2019-56-03/S0273-0979-2018-01649-2/S0273-0979-2018-01649-2.pdf).

Comment: I had seen those papers.  Aren't they studying the stability only "near the 2D Couette flow"?  So, maybe some "extreme large-scale swirling" initial conditions could stay turbulent forever?

Comment: Right, those are perturbative (near Couette) results.